# Error: "Photo data or source id must be included" when I try to Upload a photo to PicasaWeb in Gdata .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gdata, picasa

Somebody know what I'm doing wrong?

```
var service = new Service("lh2", "exampleCo-exampleApp-1");
service.setUserCredentials("myuser", "mypass");

var myPhoto = new PhotoEntry
              {
                  Title = new AtomTextConstruct(
                  AtomTextConstructElementType.Title,
                  "Puppies FTW")
              };

var myMedia = new MediaFileSource(@"C:\puppies.jpg", "image/jpeg");
myPhoto.MediaSource = myMedia;

var u="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/default";

var returnedPhoto = service.Insert(new Uri(u), myPhoto);
```

Actually is returning bad request error (400) with the following response string: **Photo data or source id must be included**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was returning error because the Uri was wrong:

I must use:

```
var u="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/media/api/user/default/albumid/default";
```

instead:

```
var u="https://picasaweb.google.com/data/feed/api/user/default/albumid/default";
```